# python openpyxl ovrewritting file

Tags: python, openpyxl

Consider the following code I have written.

```
import openpyxl

try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xls')
    print ('entered try')
except:
    wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
wb.create_sheet('test2')
wb.save('test.xls')
```

My aim was to open an excel file with the name test.xls if it exists and create sheets in it.

The first time the code runs an excel file is created as expected.
The next time I run this code it is not entering the try block but creating a new workbook and a new sheet losing existing sheets which is not expected behaviour.

Am I overlooking something? Is there a flaw in the logic that subsequent running of the code does not enter the try block? These are the specific doubts which I have.

Looking forward to some insight.

P.S : Not sure if it is relevant but I am working with Ubuntu and the excel equivalent used is LibreOffice calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

First, never ever catch all exception, and especially, don't pass them without at least print the error:

```
try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
    print ('entered try')
except Exception as e:
    print e.message
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
```

Second, the code does indeed enter the `try` cluase, but exits after the first line. When I ran your code and printed the error message, I got the following message:

> openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, please use xlrd to
>   read this file, or convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format.

This message appears even after an "xls" file was created by openpyxl, so first of all, change the file name to "test.xlsx", then things should start to work out

OLDER ANSWER

Assuming you wish to create empty worksheets, `wb.create_sheet('test2')` creates a new sheet each time invoked. You should check to see if the workbook contains the desired sheet before creating it if you wish to keep it.
If you wish to append data to an existing worksheet, you should use `ws.append(<your_data>)`, again, after checking to see whether or not the workbook contains the desired worksheet. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe that you mean to check if the sheet is already there perhaps using an if condition or something similar. One of my concerns as I said earlier was that the second time I run this code, the try block does not run but a whole new workbook object is created. Thus I lose my initial data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Jimmy Lee Jones. Just made the format change to xlsx. It working as expected. I will mark your answer as accepted.